# How to use paste mode in pyspark shell?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How to enter into paste mode in "pyspark" Spark Shell? Actually I am looking for an equivalent ":paste" command (works in Scala Spark Shell) in "pyspark". By using this mode, I would like to paste entire code snippet in shell rather than executing line by line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use IPython terminal you can paste using `%paste` / `%cpaste` magic. The first one executes code from the clipboard automatically, the second one is closer to Scala REPL `:paste` and requires termination  by `--` or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

It is also possible to use `%edit` magic which opens external editor and executes code on exit.

Standard Python shell doesn't provide similar functionality.

Comment: I don't know if there is something wrong with spark-shell but I can't paste large chunks of code into the shell in this mode without mysterious compilation errors. I have to paste it chunk by chunk, which is mildly infuriating.

Comment: how to do with spark 2.4?